# Google Calendar api Quickstart - Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('file://') does not match the recipient

Tags: google-calendar-api

I followed all the instructions on the [Google Calendar API Quickstart page](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/js) and ran the provided quickstart.html (with my Google clientID) in Chrome.  I only see the "Google Calendar API Quickstart" title.  No authorization nor Signout buttons appears at all.
When I inspect the page in Console, the following errors are displayed:
[Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow'...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wubKZ.png) See attached screenshot.

Does anyone have any clues as to what is going on? I am running python 3.6 and initiated the webserver through the "python -m http.server 8080" command prompt on the working directory the quickstart.html file is located. Thanks for your help!